# Javascript, como cambiar una imagen en HTML con JS para dark-mode

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hice esto para cambiar a modo oscuro un website (me base en un tutorial), cambia el color y todo pero la imagen NO, revise el código JS y nada. Tal vez sea la parte del if, pero nada. Agradecería su ayuda.

---

```js
let toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");
let label = document.getElementById("label");
toggle.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  let estado = event.target.checked;
  document.body.classList.toggle("dark-mood");
  if (estado == true) {
    label.innerHTML = '<img src="assets/ico/ico-sun.png" alt="sun mood" class="ico-mood"/>';
  } else {
    label.innerHTML = '<img src="assets/ico/ico-moon.png" alt="dark mood" class="ico-mood"/>';
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="c-toggle-mood">
  <label for="toggle" id="label_toggle" class="label-toggle">
        <img
          src="assets/ico/ico-moon.png"
          alt="dark mood"
          class="ico-mood"
        />
      </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
</div>
```

Comment: Creo que podría ser solo `estado`. Por ejemplo: `if (estado)` porque estado ya es true ...

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Sin embargo, ya lo probé y nada :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

El problema es porque no tienes un elemento con `id = label` así que hay que modificar la segunda línea de tu código por

```
let label = document.getElementById("label_toggle");
```

Ya que tu etiqueta `label` tiene el id `label_toggle`

```
<label for="toggle" id="label_toggle" class="label-toggle">
```

Ejemplo completo:

```js
let toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");
let label = document.getElementById("label_toggle");
toggle.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  let estado = event.target.checked;
  document.body.classList.toggle("dark-mood");
  if (estado == true) {
    label.innerHTML = '<img src="assets/ico/ico-sun.png" alt="sun mood" class="ico-mood"/>';
    console.log('sun');
  } else {
    label.innerHTML = '<img src="assets/ico/ico-moon.png" alt="dark mood" class="ico-mood"/>';
    console.log('dark');
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="c-toggle-mood">
  <label for="toggle" id="label_toggle" class="label-toggle">
        <img
          src="assets/ico/ico-moon.png"
          alt="dark mood"
          class="ico-mood"
        />
      </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
</div>
```

Comment: Si funciona!
**Muchas gracias**